# Php Yii define form field validation outwith model

Tags: php, validation, yii

I'm using yii framework in my current project. I have a page with a form (submitting to database) which defines the required fields in the rules of the model - as standard. On this page, I also have a dynamic form I've built, as a component which pulls additional fields in.

However, I need to be able to also define some of these as required fields. Is there any way of defining required fields outside of the model?

Answer (score 0):

Make following changes in your model:
- Define additional fields as public
- Add 'Required Rule' for additional fields

```
class ExampleModel extends CActiveRecord {
        // Define additional fields as public
        public $addField1;
        public $addField2;
        public $addField3;

        public function rules() {
                return array(
                        // Add 'Required Rule' for additional fields
                        array('existField1, existField2, addField1, addField2, addField3', 'required'),
                        ...
                );
        }

        public function attributeLabels() {
                return array(
                        ...,
                        'addField1' => 'Additional Field 1',
                        'addField2' => 'Additional Field 2',
                        'addField3' => 'Additional Field 3',
                );
        }
}
```

Hope this help you! Let me know if there is any concern from this.